Electron-vite application isnt working due to not finding index.html
I am working on electron-vite application and every thing about code is good but while launching in console of electron-vite it shows this messages and do not displaying the contents.
`
*The Content Security Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' is ignored when delivered via a <meta> element.
index-D8DsFqm0.js:7564 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__dirname' before initialization
    at index-D8DsFqm0.js:7564:28*

Related to this, this is my index.html file:

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Electron</title>
    <!-- Content Security Policy -->
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="
        default-src 'self';
        script-src 'self';
        style-src 'self';
        img-src 'self' data:;
        connect-src 'self';
        font-src 'self';
        object-src 'none';
        base-uri 'self';
      "
    />
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index-D8DsFqm0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="./assets/index-jmyATqTM.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>

I tried to resolve the __dirname problem manually like using
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills';
but it does not work properly.
